# ROR: Trying to trigger update route using 'put' but for some reason deleting instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a rails application I'm working on, and I'm using [devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise) for authentication. I'm having an issue where when I try to update the user details instead up updating the user the user just gets deleted.

In registrations/edit.html.erb I have:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), method: :put) do |f| %>

  ... input tags and styling

<% end %>
```

Which generates the html:

```
<form class="edit_user" id="edit_user" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/users" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="Q2U4gEBfaIwCo2Vwi2fwXgwYLjzE4HpoDC8KN52m2GGqEdb94jd/c3TyFhEJtQEziHat9zFQs+e+fRJp4/j2WA==" />

... rest of the input tags

</form>
```

The key thing here being `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />` in rails this should trigger the PUT route but for some reason when I submit the form it's triggering the delete route:

```
Started DELETE "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-06-01 16:15:48 +0100
   (0.6ms)  SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
   (0.2ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.`version` FROM `schema_migrations` ORDER BY `schema_migrations`.`version` ASC
```

Has anyone come across this before and know what could be causing it?

**EDIT**

my config/routes.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  namespace :admin do
      resources :users

      root to: "users#index"
    end
  devise_for :users, module: 'users'
  get 'profile', to: 'profile#index'
  root to: "home#index"
end
```

Comment: Share your routes.rb file or hit "rake routes" command on console and share results.

Comment: Sure, added to the post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was just being silly. amongst the input fields there was a ERB [button_to](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) helper for canceling the account (or rather deleting the user) this helper was rendering a form inside the update form and that inner form was what was being submitted when hitting the submit button on the outer form, causing the delete action to be triggered

**EDIT:** To be clear the way to avoid this is to make sure the [button_to](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) helper is outside the form you're wanting to submit or on a separate page.